# Retrieving images from a removable device

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to retrieve images from a removable device upon loading my program. When I run the program I want it to automatically check for any removable devices and retrieve any image files that are found in any of the directories to an image list box. The code I have is as follows:

```
        private void DemoForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        System.IO.DriveInfo[] drives = System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (System.IO.DriveInfo drive in drives)
        {
            if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Found removable drive " + drive.Name.ToString());


                //Loop for all removable drives
                Console.WriteLine(drive.Name.ToString());

                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\", "*.jpg,*.jpeg",  //Find all .jpeg and .jpg on this drive & add.
                                      SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                imageListView1.Items.Add(filePaths.ToString());

            }
        }
    }
```

It's hard coded to search the E:\ drive at the moment because I don't know how to search for any removable device. This code brings back one blank thumbnail named "System.String[]". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *I don't know how to search for any removable device* - your code already works on removable drives only, use `drive.RootDirectory` to remove hard coded E:\

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.ToString()` on an Array just returns the type of the array, in this case `System.String[]`.  Try looping over the strings in the `filePaths` array and adding them to the `imageListView1.Items`.

As for the hardcoded `E:\`, you already have the removable `drive` from the foreach loop.  Call `drive.Name` to get the drive name instead of `E:\`.